# c# Blazored.Typehead type arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazored

I'm trying to add a search box with Blazor using Blazored Typehead but I'm getting this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'TypeInference.CreateBlazoredTypeahead_0<TItem, TValue>(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int, Func<string, Task<IEnumerable>>, int, TValue, int, EventCallback, int, Expression<Func>, int, RenderFragment, int, RenderFragment, int, RenderFragment)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  SEP3-FrontEnd   C:\Users\JimAnt\source\repos\SEP3-FrontEnd\SEP3-FrontEnd\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Razor\Shared\TopMenu.razor.g.cs    101 Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'TypeInference.CreateBlazoredTypeahead_0<TItem, TValue>(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int, Func<string, Task<IEnumerable>>, int, TValue, int, EventCallback, int, Expression<Func>, int, RenderFragment, int, RenderFragment, int, RenderFragment)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  SEP3-FrontEnd   C:\Users\JimAnt\source\repos\SEP3-FrontEnd\SEP3-FrontEnd\Shared\TopMenu.razor   1   Active

My code:

```
@using SEP3_FrontEnd.Models
@using SEP3_FrontEnd.Data
@inject IUserService IuserService;
@inject IChatService IChatService;
@inject User user;  

<BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="@SearchUsers" @bind-Value="selectedUser">
    <SelectedTemplate>
        @context.Equals(user.UserName)
    </SelectedTemplate>
    <ResultTemplate>
        @context.Equals(user.UserName)
    </ResultTemplate>
    <NotFoundTemplate>
        Sorry, there weren't any users with that name
    </NotFoundTemplate>
</BlazoredTypeahead>

@code {
    private User selectedUser;

    private async Task<User> SearchUsers(string searchText)
    {
        return await IuserService.SearchUser(searchText);
        
    }
}
```

And also part of the other inbuilt class that this error shows up in:

```
public partial class TopMenu : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{
    #pragma warning disable 1998
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        __Blazor.SEP3_FrontEnd.Shared.TopMenu.TypeInference.CreateBlazoredTypeahead_0(__builder, 0, 1,
```

I'm fairly new to C# so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First off, your SearchUsers method should return a `Task<IEnumerable<User>>` - not a single user.  I had issues with @bind-Value that I resolved by using the ValueChanged method instead. Let me know if you need details.